# Column filter checkbox not updated

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Consider a column in ag-grid that can only have one of two values, "Yes" and "No" as strings.

ag-grid has a built in column filter that shows all distinct values of that column with checkboxes.

[Yes and No options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3yYR.jpg)

This filtering works great with user interaction, but I need to filter out the rows with "No" values prior to first render, **without user interaction**.

I can accomplish the desired filtering via the use of

```
gridOptions.isExternalFilterPresent
gridOptions.doesExternalFilterPass
```

However, when the user clicks the filter button they only see options for values that are currently in the column, not all possible values.

[Yes only filter options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vac4r.jpg)

The problem is that the user may not even know that "No" is a possible option and will not know what that the grid is currently filtered.

I believe in order to help with this scenario, you supply all possible values can specify for the filter as [filterParams](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-set/#set-filter-parameters) below:

```
{
  headerName: 'ETF',
  field: 'isEtf',
  filterParams: {
    values: ['Yes', 'No'],
    suppressRemoveEntries: true
  }
}
```

When I supply `values` the grid will show both checkboxes, but it is not accurate as all "No" values have been filtered out and should have an un-checked checkbox next to the "No" option.

Setting true for `suppressRemoveEntries` seems to have no effect even though its description seems to suggest that this would address my issue.

Is there a way to control the state of the checkboxes programmatically or to have the grid reset/recognize current filter options against possible values supplied in `filterParams.values` after my external filter is applied?

Answer (score 0):

I never found a solution using an external filter, but utilizing the set filter created by the grid achieved the intended result.

```
const filter: IFilterComp = gridOptions.api.getFilterInstance('isEtf');

// bracket notation required because current typing does not include 
// the unselectValue function as of ag-grid v17.1.1
filter['unselectValue']('No');

// you must let grid know of the change so it will be applied to data in grid
gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();
```